# How to model a 2x2x2 dataset for a 3 way repeated measures ANOVA analysis

Tags: anova, spss, repeated-measures, dataset

I have some data derived from a 2x2x2 experimental design. There are 3 IV's, each with 2 levels. My DV is reaction time (measured in seconds). I've used a repeated measures design (n=10). I have 20 repetitions per condition, per participant. I am interested in the effects of image rotation, shape, and colour on my DV (reaction time) and want to check the 3 main effects (rotation, shape, colour), the 3 interactions (rotation x shape, rotation x colour, shape x colour), and the 3 way interaction (rotation x shape x colour).

```
IV's:
rotation: 90, 180
shape: triangle, square
colour: black, white

DV:
Reaction time (s)
```

I am unsure how to model this dataset so that I can analyze it using a repeated measures 2x2x2 ANOVA. (For what it's worth, I will be using SPSS to analyze the data.)

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but
you may have a real statistical question buried here. 
You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying 
statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: Ok, thank you for informing me, I will be sure to check what is off-topic in future. I genuinly cannot find any help online with regard to entering data from a 3 way (2x2x2) ANOVA.

Comment: Well, you might edit your question to ask how to model such data *in general* (not how to use SPSS). Once you know the answer to that, you may find it easier to figure out the SPSS aspects.

Comment: What can I do to get this question answered, is there a way to re-post it?

Comment: Please *do not* repost. If you can think of a relevant edit, that will 'bump' the question to the top of the main page. Beyond that, you need to wait for someone to come along with an answer.

Comment: How will someone come along? Surely it's far down the list, no one is going to scroll back.